# ML.Net soccer prediction returns incorrect results

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I have the following code in ML.NET which reads historic football matches odds and results and the tries to predict result based on passed odds but the prediction is disappointing and every time it gives different prediction even if I use the exact same data.

```
public ResultPrediction Start()
{
    var dbData = matchDetailsRepository.GetOdds(string.Empty);
    if (dbData.Count == 0)
        return null;

    //Create ML Context with seed for repeteable/deterministic results
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);

    IDataView data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<FullTimeOddsData>(dbData.ToFullTimeOddsDataList());

    var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: "Result")
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "HomeWinOdd", "DrawOdd", "AwayWinOdd"));

    // Define StochasticDualCoordinateAscent regression algorithm estimator
    var sdcaEstimator = pipeline.Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features"));

    // Build machine learning model
    TransformerChain<RegressionPredictionTransformer<LinearRegressionModelParameters>> trainedModel = sdcaEstimator.Fit(data);

    // Create PredictionEngines
    PredictionEngine<FullTimeOddsData, ResultPrediction> predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<FullTimeOddsData, ResultPrediction>(trainedModel);

    // Input Data
    FullTimeOddsData inputData = new FullTimeOddsData
    {
        HomeWinOdd = 19F,
        DrawOdd = 10F,
        AwayWinOdd = 1.14F,
    };

    // Get Prediction
    ResultPrediction prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(inputData);

    return prediction;
}

public class ResultPrediction
{
    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float Prediction;
}

public class FullTimeOddsData
{
    public float HomeWinOdd;

    public float DrawOdd;

    public float AwayWinOdd;

    public float Result;
}
```

What is the problem here which gives different prediction using the same data and what am I doing wrong to give wrong prediction. Based on the input data the prediction must be 1 or near 1

Sample data below:

```
HomeWinOdd,DrawOdd,AwayWinOdd,Result
2.2,3.5,2.5,2
2,3,2.9,2
2.05,3.4,2.95,2
2,3.4,2.9,2
2,3.6,2.65,3
2.1,3,2.8,3
2.3,3.4,2.55,3
2.4,3.3,2.4,3
2.3,3.3,2.45,3
2.35,3,2.35,3
2.45,3.4,2.4,3
2.4,3.3,2.4,3
1.9,3.3,3.5,1
1.8,3,3.5,1
1.85,3.4,3.5,1
1.41,4.1,4.7,1
1.75,3.1,3.6,1
1.6,3.5,4.5,1
1.61,3.6,4.2,1

Result = 1 means Home wins
Result = 2 means Away wins
Result = 3 means Draw
```

Comment: Machine learning is suppose to give same results each time.  If the probability of team A winning is 60% and team B winning is 40%  does team A always win?

Comment: SDCA is a stochastic algorithms, it's really hard to make it deterministic. Maybe try to use some other model?

Also, I would question why you try to solve it as a regression problem? Multi-class classification seems a more natural choice